# How can I get rid of "Can not find: admin-extra.html" error

Tags: solr

I am using the newest SOLR 4.10.1. I have a simple configuration with 2 cores. Every time I open the SOLR admin interface, I get the following errors:

```
Can not find: admin-extra.html
Can not find: admin-extra.menu-top.html
Can not find: admin-extra.menu-bottom.html
```

How can I get rid of these errors? Do I have to create these files? I do not want to do this because I do not need these files.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These files are used in the Solr admin interface for each specific core's overview page. You can just create empty files in the conf directory to stop it from complaining.

Comment: Do I really have to create these files? I would say that this a bug in SOLR. The files should be optional and not having them should not result in any error.

Comment: I just reported the error to the SOLR team - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-6688 . We'll see what they will say.

Answer (score 0):

Whoever is not interested to create empty files as previously suggested, there's another option I tried and it worked for me. To achieve this it's necessary to edit SOLR webapps files which are trying to load admin-extra components. I have edited following files:

```
.../solr-webapp/webapp/css/styles/dashboard.css
.../solr-webapp/webapp/js/scripts/dashboard.js
.../solr-webapp/webapp/tpl/dashboard.html
```